# Dynamic content not listening to show/hide functions

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically creating elements inside a loop

```
m += '<input type="text" id="deadline_input_' + data[i].data.sequence + '" value="' + (data[i].deadline == "-" ? '' : data[i].deadline) + '" data-seq="' + data[i].data.sequence + '" class="hasDatepicker deadline_input" dateFormat="DD-MM-YYYY" style="display:none;" />';

m += '<span id="deadline_text_' + data[i].data.sequence + '">' + data[i].deadline + '</span>';

$('#results_projects').append(m);
```

but then when I use

```
$("#deadline_input_" + $(this).data("seq")).show();
$("#deadline_text_" + $(this).data("seq")).hide();
```

inside an ajax call, they are not changing. I know the ajax call is succeeding because I have added a `console.log("success")` inside my success which shows in the console

my full ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
                    url : '/section/projects',
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {
                        "action": "update_deadline",
                        "sequence": $(this).data("seq"),
                        "deadline": $(this).val(),
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("success");
                        $("#deadline_input_" + $(this).data("seq")).hide();
                        $("#deadline_text_" + $(this).data("seq")).show();
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        alert("There was an error updateing the Project");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Does console logging `$(this).data("seq")` show the proper value?

Comment: ^^^ Keep in mind the value of `this` changes within the success callback `function(){}`, like most `this` do.  You can put `context: this` on the ajax properties to force the context to remain the same in the success callback